# Mange Phone calls in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to manage phone calls on my app.
I have managed to find this code which starts a phone call

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+et.getText().toString()));
startActivity(i);
```

but no luck in finding how to reject / end a call.
something like a button on my app which will end the current if there is one.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You can't.  Every time a way is found, Google has purposely removed it.  There's a variety of financial attacks possible via phone calls, and Google wants to just remove the capability to prevent them.

Comment: there is an app called MacroDroid which can do things like that. (hang/answer/call etc...)

Comment: If they found a way to do it, I assure you that it will be eliminated in the next version.  They've eliminated every way people have found for the last decade.  Unless of course you replace the default dialer.  Its functionality Google doesn't want apps to have.